# AngularJS: How to call $animate.enter()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

Say now I have these:

```
var ngModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate']);
ngModule.animation('.my-crazy-animation', function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) { ... },
    leave: function(element, done) { ... },
    move: function(element, done) { ... },
    beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done) { ... },
    addClass: function(element, className, done) { ... },
    beforeRemoveClass: function(element, className, done) { ... },
    removeClass: function(element, className, done) { ... }
  };
});
```

But how to call the `enter`, `leave` functions? Please give a working example of calling `$animate.enter()`?

Comment: You're not meant to call these animation property functions explicitly. Directives such as `ng-repeat` (i.e. able to trigger `enter`, `leave` and `move`) automatically invoke animation properties pertinent to them as the DOM changes. If you've not seen it already, there is a working example in the __[official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)__.

Comment: @miqid I've seen the documentation, but it still doesn't make much sense. What if I want to call some js animations without having to `enter` or `leave` any element? Do I have to invoke them using `addClass` and `removeClass`? If I just want to call a simple TweenMax animation, is it even recommended to use ng-animate?

Comment: Whether the animation properties are relevant to you depends on the directives you're using. For example, with `ng-repeat` you'll notice in the __[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js)__ that `$animate.enter()`, `$animate.leave()` and `$animate.move()` are all explicitly called somewhere, which is why they're relevant. Use of `$animate` isn't mandatory, but it promotes reusability of animations across your application.